# How to get around "convert varchar to float" error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar

I have a table that has non-numeric values in the source.
I am using a CTE to filter down to a set of values that is all numeric.

However, when I try to convert the filtered list to float, I get an error.

Goal is to find all Lab Results that are less than 8.0

CTE:

```
;with labs AS (

    SELECT  LabResult_Result
    FROM VIEW_PatientLabResult
    WHERE (LabResult_DateTimeOfObservation between '1/1/2012' and '1/1/2013') and
       MasterLabCode_Description='Hemoglobin (Hgb) A1c' 

)
```

Results in ~250 rows, all of which are decimal (manually checked).

Cannot get to convert them to float for comparison. Best I have so far is:

```
select * from 
    (
            select *, CAST( labresult_result as float) as Converted
            FROM labs
    ) Conv
    WHERE Conv.Converted < 8.0
```

This results in `Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Without the `WHERE` clause, the query runs fine.

I am thinking that SQL is trying to convert the entire results before the CTE filter.  Is there a way to make it run in order?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Well, why are you storing float values in a varchar column?

Comment: It's not my choice.  I do not have input into the design of the database.

Comment: Well you should still let the designers know that they have done a poor job.

Comment: WHERE isnumeric(labresult_result)=1

Answer (score 0):

SQL only guarantees the order of execution when you use a `case` statement.  (Although as Aaron points out, this is *not* true for aggregated values in a `group by` expression.)

Try this instead:

```
select *
from (select *, (case when ISNUMERIC(labresult_result) = 1 then CAST(labresult_result as float)
                 end) as Converted
      FROM labs
     ) conv
where conv.converted < 8.0
```

In the original query, SQL is free to rearrange the `where` clauses to optimize the query -- even between CTEs and subqueries.  This can result in an unexpected error.  Remember, SQL is a descriptive language that describes the output, not a procedural language that specifies how things are processed.

Comment: (1) ISNUMERIC is not a boolean - you need to compare it e.g. `= 1`. (2) ISNUMERIC is not a good solution - it returns true for values that can't be converted to float, e.g. `e`.

Comment: Also, CASE is an expression, not a statement (semantics are important), and CASE doesn't always guarantee order of execution, e.g. when aggregates are involved.

Comment: (Not my down-vote, btw, but I think these updates should be part of your answer.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The aggregation limitation did not seem relevant to the original question, but I mention it anyway.  For those who are downvoting -- assuming it is because of the lack of `= 1` after `isnumeric()` . . . You might put your efforts into writing your own answer that is correct.

Comment: It is also true for fulltext clauses - my comment was about it being dangerous to promise something that isn't always true (regardless if it is true in this case or not, your sentence will be read by plenty of people aside from the OP).